# Find the highest point on the cardioid $r = 1 + \cos(\theta)$

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I'm stuck on this. I don't know where to start!

The problem:

Find the highest  point on the cardioid $r = 1 + \cos(\theta)$

Comment: Find the $y$-coordinate in terms of $\theta$ first

Comment: I would hope that the highest point corresponds to a horizontal tangent line. So if you can express $dy/dx$ in terms of these coordinates, you could set $dy/dx=0$ and try to find a solution.

Comment: Hint: $y = r\sin \theta$. Hence $y =  (1 + \cos\theta)\sin\theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Simon S said, use $y = r\sin \theta$ to get $y =  (1 + \cos\theta)\sin\theta$. Then set $dy/d\theta=0$ to maximize $y$:
$$
\frac{dy}{d\theta} = (1+\cos\theta)\cos\theta - \sin^2\theta = 0
$$
Use $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$ to write the equation above as:
$$
2\cos^2\theta + \cos\theta - 1 = 0
$$
The possible solutions are $\cos\theta = 1/2$ and $\cos\theta = -1$. Inspection shows that $\theta = \pi/3$ (or $60º$) is the correct answer.

([Plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20r%3D1%2Bcos%28theta%29) and [answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize%20sin%28theta%29%281%2Bcos%28theta%29%29%20for%20theta%20from%20-pi%20to%20pi) on WolframAlpha)

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot and I was able to do the next one on my own.